# How to show Modal in React Native using Functional Component imported from another file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am showing a view Login.js and in that view on button click, I need to render modal, that I have separated and written in another file named Countries.js.

On Login.js file I have imported Countries.js and on button click, I am doing this:

```js
show_modal = () => {
    <Countries/>
}
```

but nothing is happening. I am a noob I just started React Native kindly help me.

Countries.js code:

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import {
Alert,
Modal,
Text,
TouchableHighlight,
View
} from "react-native";

const Countries = () => {

    console.log('called');
    
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);
    
    return (
    
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>
    
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3" }}
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.openButton}
        onPress={() => {
          setModalVisible(true);
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Show Modal</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>)
};
    
export default Countries;
```

Comment: hi,can you add Countries.js code so we can se why its not working but  from first look my guess is since you didnt any props in Countries component it  does not know what to do.

Comment: some imports I didn't mention here.

Comment: You can passing props for modalVisible=true and use modal component ,

Comment: where i use modal component?

Comment: You see i already set the state of modal true by default. Waleed Nasir

Comment: @NeoMurphy just add return in you show_modal function and then let me know

Answer (score 2):

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import {Modal, View, Text, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import CountryModal from 'path to outsource country modal file';

const login = (props)=>{
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);

return(

<View>
    <TouchableHighlight
style={styles.openButton}
onPress={() => {
    setModalVisible(true);
}}
>
<Text style={styles.textStyle}>Show Modal</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

<CountryModal isVisible={modalVisible} setModalVisiblity = {()=>{setModalVisible(preState=> preState = !preState)}}>
</View>
)
}

export default login;
```

**Country Modal file**

```
import React from react;
import {Modal} from 'react-native';

const Country = (props)=>{

return (
<Modal
    animationType="slide"

    transparent={true}
    visible={isVisible}
    onRequestClose={() => {
      Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
    }}
  >
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <View style={styles.modalView}>
        <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3" }}
          onPress={() => {props.setModalVisiblity
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </View>
  </Modal>
)
}
```

*Hope you got your answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
show_modal = ()=> {
  <Countries/>
}
```

to this:

```
show_modal = ()=> {
  return  <Countries/>; // add return keyword 
}
```

the above function will return `undefined` if return id is not explicitly defined

Comment: Can you give a try in your app and then answer?

Comment: where are you call this function show_modal? in react native

Comment: inside Login.js file

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this modal directly with other components.
Example code

```js
export default function Login() {

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Toggle Modal" onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
      // other login page code
      <Countries visible={visible} /> // or any other modal, add direclty to the screen you need to show the modal at
    </View>
  )

}
```

Comment: Sir i didnt set any props for Countries.

Comment: You should remove the `visible` state from the modal to the parent component. Because it's the state of the parent component, that the modal should be shown or not. 
So your modal would not contain any state, rather shift the state logic to upper component.